# How can I expose my settings to other classes

Tags: c#, silverlight, architecture, prism

I have an application.

I login.

I make a web call and get a bunch of settings.

I publish an eventaggregator event that sends these settings to any other class that wants to listen and grab them.

To me this just seems like the wrong design.  For a loosely coupled project what is the best way to share a bunch of settings in a class?  I know I could make a static global, but that does not sound loosely coupled either!

Comment: Very interesting question, I've been using the static class way and I think like you. Hope somebody answers :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may define `ISettingsProvider` interface and use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [IoC containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) like [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) or [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) to inject this interface implementation to any class you would like to and use it there.

It will be loosely coupled because you will not have dependency to real setting provider implementation and it will be possible change implementation easily (e.g for unit testing).